# Problems log in in app after changin firestore database

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, service, firebase-authentication

so I've received a project where to develop they cloned the original firestore database and gave it to us to use whyle developing.

The data in both databases are the same, when I log in trying to use the new database it gives the error that the user does not exist.
I'm not sure what is happening here.

the service:

```
    constructor(
    private firestore: Firestore,
    private router: Router,
    private fns: AngularFireFunctions,
    private auth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    this.auth.authState.subscribe(
      (user) => ((this.userObservable = user, console.log(this.userObservable)))
    );
  }
    
      login(email: any, password: any) {
        this.auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(
            async (res: any) => {
              this.sendEmailVerification(res.user);
              console.log((await res.user.getIdTokenResult()).claims);
              if ((await res.user.getIdTokenResult()).claims.roles == undefined) {
                res.user
                  .getIdTokenResult()
                  .then((res: any) =>
                    this.router.navigate(['dashboardAluno/'])
                  );
              } else if (
                (await res.user.getIdTokenResult()).claims.roles.includes('admin')
              ) {
                this.router.navigate(['admin']);
              } else {
                this.router.navigate(['login']);
              }
            },
            (err: FirebaseError) => this.emitError(err.code)
          )
          .catch((error) => {
            this.emitError(error.message);
          });
      }    
    }
```

the component.ts:

```
login(){
    this.user.login(this.email,this.password);
  }
```

I removed the authentication from the application and I only want to use the data from my firestore database.
What's wrong with the code?
Do i need to change what i'm calling, because i'm calling AngularFireAuth, should i call the db?

the error that i'm getting in console

[image]

Comment: The error auth/user-not-found thrown if there is no user corresponding to the given email. Have you tried to check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword)?

Comment: Hello Sarah, so I've tried to use this doc, yes. But as I explained in the begining everything is fucntion with the other firebase database, the functions works with it, they cloned it, and I'm grabbing the info from the new database. So the values exists, but what i think the problem is that in the first database authentication was used, then whenever I created a user it goes both to authentication and to the firestore database, i want to grab only the info from firestore database and authenticate from there.

Comment: I wanted to capture within my typescript all the data that I have in my firestore database so I can debug it, but I'm having troubles doing it.
This data comes from an especific collection within the firestore

Comment: Authentication Failed will still appear even if you have user data in Firebase Firestore since no users are stored in Firebase Auth. Could you try to clone your Firebase Auth first?

Comment: Well I have an idea, tell me if i'm wrong...I have a service where I get all users, i could build something using the info coming from there and making the login thorugh that

Comment: Yes, and the Firebase Auth comes from the same project.